# Mount file system path as encrypted?

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs, encfs

I know how to mount an encrypted ext4 partition. However, now I want to do the opposite. I want to mount a folder of an existing partition somewhere else in my filesystem, but when accessing it, files should get encrypted using AES256. Is that possible?

Here an example: I have a folder containing some images 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, etc. I want to mount this folder in another location so that the content of the images are encrypted. Filenames shouldn't change.

Background: I want to synchronise my image folder to a cloud storage, but I want to encrypt the files before upload. The tools provided by the cloud provider don't support client side encryption. Therefore, I want to use the tools on a folder only containing encrypted data.

Comment: As it stands now, it seems I'm looking for something like encfs with the `--reverse` option. Unfortunately, encfs wasn't updated since 2010 and there are some known security problems. More modern stuff seems to be missing reverse option.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rsync with encryption. Pretty foolproof once it's set up.

http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/off-site-encrypted-backups-using-rsync-and-aes/

Comment: Even if the author named the article RSync, he actually uses duplicity :-)